# from testing in sqlite to postgres primary key starts in a different pk

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, django-testing

I am running into a problem when passing from development to production.

On the test, sqlite starts the pk in 1 (The first Propuesta object that I create has pk==1) , postgres starts it in 9 (I don't get why , running Propuesta.objects.count() I get 10, so there shoudn't be nothing else before ).

This makes my test fail, cause is expecting 1 in the url as pk, how can I fix this behavior ?

I have the following test:

```
class PropuestaDetailViewTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.concejo_1 = Alcance.objects.create(nombre_pais="España", nombre_provincia="Asturias",
                                           nombre_concejo="Castrillon")

        cls.categoria = Categoria.objects.create(titulo="ambiente", descripcion="test")

        number_of_proponsals = 10
        for proponsal_num in range(number_of_proponsals):
            cls.propuesta = Propuesta.objects.create(titulo="titulo_" + proponsal_num.__str__(),
                                                 descripcion="des_" + proponsal_num.__str__(),
                                                 creador_de_la_propuesta=User.objects.first(),
                                                 localizacion=cls.concejo_1)

            cls.propuesta.categorias.add(cls.categoria)

def test_context(self):
    resp = self.client.get(reverse('participation:detail-view', kwargs={'propuesta_id': 1, 'slug': 'titulo_0'}))
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTrue(resp.context['propuesta'].titulo == 'titulo_0')
    self.assertTrue(resp.context['que_ha_votado'] == 0)
    self.assertTrue(resp.context['is_user_authenticated'] == 'false')
```

And

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by _sqlite starts the pk in 1 , postgres starts it in 9_ ?

Comment: The first Propuesta that I create it has the pk== 1 in sqlite , in postgres the first one has pk==9

Comment: Well, have you ever deleted some `Propuesta` that you previously created in your Postgres table?

Comment: Why does this matter in any way at all? The pk is an arbitrary number and nothing should be relying on it; your test shouldn't expect any particular number.